# Python scraping href adjust url

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, keyword

This code works for the URL http://www.schulliste.eu/schule/ but not for 
http://www.schulliste.eu/type/gymnasien/
Does anybody know why? I think it has something to do with the keyword "title"
Also I like to have the plain email adresses (without brackets and quotes) among themselves, is that possible?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

def get_emails(_links: list, _r=[0, 10]):
    for i in range(*_r):
        new_d = soup(requests.get(_links[i]).text,         'html.parser').find_all('a', {'class':'my_modal_open'})

        if new_d:
            yield new_d[-1]['title']

d = soup(requests.get('http://www.schulliste.eu/schule/').text, 'html.parser')

results = [i['href'] for i in d.find_all('a')][52:-9]
print(list(get_emails(results)))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess that it does not work, b/c searched item `'a', {'class':'my_modal_open'}` is not found by the second link.
2. To print it without quotes, you could try this:

`items = list(get_emails(results))
    for item in items:
        print(item)`

Comment: But the second link has the class my_modal_open and a: <a     href="http://application_v2.just4web.cz/templates/box_email.php?    email=elsterschloss-gymnasium.elsterwerda@schulen.brandenburg.de&amp;id_lang=10&amp;hide_email=0" class="my_modal_open" data-popup-order="0">elsterschloss-gymnasium.elsterwerda<img src="http://application_v2.just4web.cz/img/icon_at.png" alt="E-mail" style="margin:0px;border:none;">schulen.brandenburg.de</a>